# Convert a dataframe with multiple columns to a two-columns avoiding duplicates with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe like this

```
        c1     c2      c3    c4     c5   value
4     gray   gray    blue  gray  black  181647
5    brown  black    gray  blue   gray   78917
8     gray   gray    gray  gray  black  193894
19    gray  black    gray  gray   gray  100714
20    gray  green   green  gray  black  102411
23    gray  black     red   red   blue  180665
26    gray  black    gray  gray   gray  147997
27  yellow   gray  yellow  gray   gray   91169
```

I would like to transform it, considering one mapping color-value for each row avoiding duplicates. So that it will output this:

```
         c   value
0     gray  181647
1     blue  181647
2    black  181647
3    brown   78917
4    black   78917
5     gray   78917
6     blue   78917
7     gray  193894
8    black  193894
9     gray  100714
10   black  100714
11    gray  102411
12   green  102411
13   black  102411
14    gray  180665
15   black  180665
16     red  180665
17    blue  180665
18    gray  147997
19   black  147997
20  yellow   91169
21    gray   91169
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), remove `variable` column and remove duplicates by both columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('value', value_name='c', ignore_index=False)
         .sort_index()
         .drop('variable', 1)
         .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True))
print (df1)
     value       c
0   181647    gray
1   181647   black
2   181647    blue
3    78917    gray
4    78917   black
5    78917    blue
6    78917   brown
7   193894   black
8   193894    gray
9   100714    gray
10  100714   black
11  102411    gray
12  102411   green
13  102411   black
14  180665    blue
15  180665     red
16  180665   black
17  180665    gray
18  147997    gray
19  147997   black
20   91169    gray
21   91169  yellow
```

Or use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for unpivot:

```
df1 = df.set_index('value').stack().droplevel(1).reset_index(name='c').drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
     value       c
0   181647    gray
2   181647    blue
4   181647   black
5    78917   brown
6    78917   black
7    78917    gray
8    78917    blue
10  193894    gray
14  193894   black
15  100714    gray
16  100714   black
20  102411    gray
21  102411   green
24  102411   black
25  180665    gray
26  180665   black
27  180665     red
29  180665    blue
30  147997    gray
31  147997   black
35   91169  yellow
36   91169    gray
```

Last if order of columns is important use subset:

```
df1 = df1[['c','value']]
```